# VBA, avoid repeating AND, inside an IF statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

I need some help with editing a VBA code. What I am trying to do is to avoid repeating AND inside an IF statement.

So far I have this, and it works like a charm.

```
If Range("B1") <> "MatDescr" And Range("B2") <> "MatDescr" And Range("B3") <> "MatDescr" Then
MsgBox "Column 'B' does not contain MatDescr"
...rest of the code...
```

So, as mentioned above I want to avoid using so many ANDs inside the code as I will have to write this in some other codes as well. 
What currently came to my mind, was to shorten the code by writing this:

```
Dim s As Integer 
For s = 1 To 3
If Cells(s, 2) <> "MatDescr" Then
next s 
rest of the code
```

This looks much better, but in this way, VBA sees that statement as I am trying to use OR, instead of AND. Which is not what I am aiming for.

Comment: you can define a function that will perform the check and return True or False. It can take as arguments the range and the text/value to check. Then it will be convenient to use it everywhere in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be [evaluated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) as Excel array formula like this :

```
If [AND(B1:B3 <> "MatDescr")] Then
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, what you really want to know it whether your value `"MatDescr"` is present in the range `B1:B3`, which you can test using the following code.

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B3").Find("MatDescr") Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Column 'B' does not contain MatDescr"
End If
```

I took the liberty to insert the implicit call to `ActiveSheet` here you are making with the unqualifie `Range` calls. 
The `Range.Find` method searches for the first cell containing the target value and returns `Nothing` if the result is not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Application.CountIf([B1:B3], "MatDescr") = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Match

```
If IsError(Application.Match("MatDescr", ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B3"),0)) Then MsgBox "Column 'B' does not contain MatDescr"
```